# How to set SAP VARIABLES on MDX Query during COPY DATA on Data Factory?

Tags: mdx, azure-data-factory, sap-bw

I'm trying to get copy data from a SAP BW on-premisses to a CSV file on Blob Storage using MDX connection.
When I run this query on BEX Analyzer, the SAP popup a screen where insert a date range, this isn't an optional variable.
The point is, I have no idea on how to do this during the Copy Data on Azure Data Factory.

I've unsuccessfully tested Where Clause, SAP VARIABLES and FILTER()

**QUERY**:

```
SELECT
    { [Measures].[9M8SVJVCT2BZ52DZQ58MOL7TJ],
    [Measures].[9M8SVJVCT2BZ52DZQ58MOLKGN] } ON COLUMNS
FROM ZSD_I28/Y_CBA_ZSD_I28_TM1_001
WHERE  ([ZSD_I28___F38].[2019/02]:[ZSD_I28___F38].[2019/02])
```

**MESSAGE ERROR:**

```
'Type=Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupValueException,Message=SAP Business Warehouse: Entrar um valor para a variável Ano civil/mês (Intervalo de valores).,Source=Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ProviderCommon,'. Activity ID:93e3ab50-92e0-4883-ae02-88e28b9a69ce
```

**TRANSLATION:**
Entrar um valor para a variável Ano civil/mês (Intervalo de valores)Enter a variable value for Year/Month (Range Value)

**[ZSD_I28___F38 -]** This is the Year/Month column that should receive the param.

**[Check this print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRUqn.png)**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

currently we don't have support on parameters via MDX in our SAP BW connector. We did have an alternative connector on Open Hub which should have better performance and support on filtering. do you think that can work for your scenario?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-business-warehouse-open-hub